# How can one deploy elasticsearch on docker swarm without declaring a service for each es node?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-swarm

My idea here was to specifically put set the endpoint_mode to dnsrr in hopes that each elasticsearch task in the service would pick up a random IP address when starting the discovery seeding process.  This did not work.  What happens it that it goes into a loop while seeding and never decides on a master.  *I specifically want to find some elegant configuration to deploy this on every node that doesn't include static configuration files or multiple service declarations in the compose-file*.

```
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.3
    environment:
      - cluster.name=es-cluster
      - discovery.type=zen
      - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
    volumes:
      - elasticsearch_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elasticsearch
    deploy:
      mode: global
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr

volumes:
  ...
  elasticsearch_data:

networks:
  ...
  elasticsearch:
```

After deploying I just see this in the logs repeatedly (for each task):

```
web-services_elasticsearch.0.a6ilzu8ev6sp@dsnode3.<redacted>    | {"type": "server",
"timestamp": "2020- 11-10T21:47:38,443Z", "level": "WARN", "component": 
"o.e.c.c.ClusterFormationFailureHelper", "cluster.name": "es-cluster", "node.name": 
"718a5740c014", "message": "master not discovered yet, this node has not previously 
joined a bootstrapped (v7+) cluster, and this node must discover master-eligible 
nodes [elasticsearch] to bootstrap a cluster: have discovered [{718a5740c014}
{wMUW_UyQSzSxJDaz5jYVUw} {iBXmoZqHSp24fKSEUvuUpw}{10.0.46.129}{10.0.46.129:9300}
{dilmrt} {ml.machine_memory=67428794368, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true, 
ml.max_open_jobs=20}, {99680d51349a}{BBqgO_1wRamiJZGibrhVTw}{WH6Oy5gOR1Cqs-2LUzu9Mw}
{10.0.46.123} {10.0.46.123:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=67424575488, 
ml.max_open_jobs=20,  xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true}, {27bf85fa9967}
{Fm9r8aX4Rr-xa8AF_dUaLQ} {LsL5cXghTayDtXtLeWGV3Q}{10.0.46.126}{10.0.46.126:9300}
{dilmrt} {ml.machine_memory=67424575488, ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, 
transform.node=true},  {fc2900a7227a}{FUztkTZQQuWqi3lyuOOfSQ}{JzACTEvzSnepc9RGXBXCzw}
{10.0.46.131} {10.0.46.131:9300}{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=67428794368, 
ml.max_open_jobs=20,  xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true}, {7b23784db269}
{Dn472Qx5RyekUMY2jeLjIA}{w- m1g1BtS6SzZkttZEidnA}{10.0.46.122}{10.0.46.122:9300}
{dilmrt}{ml.machine_memory=67424575488,  ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, 
transform.node=true}, {7d41b0583448} {1pj_6kJZQu6n39waIzcvQQ}{xwNHOG15Q_6jwY20BbBuyQ}
{10.0.46.125}{10.0.46.125:9300}{dilmrt} {ml.machine_memory=67428794368, 
ml.max_open_jobs=20, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true}];  discovery will 
continue using [10.0.46.123:9300, 10.0.46.126:9300, 10.0.46.131:9300, 
10.0.46.122:9300,  10.0.46.125:9300] from hosts providers and [{718a5740c014}
{wMUW_UyQSzSxJDaz5jYVUw} {iBXmoZqHSp24fKSEUvuUpw}{10.0.46.129}{10.0.46.129:9300}
{dilmrt} {ml.machine_memory=67428794368, xpack.installed=true, transform.node=true,
ml.max_open_jobs=20}]  from last-known cluster state; node term 0, last-accepted 
version 0 in term 0" }
```

I feel like it's just a matter of the node.name not matching the hostname or something BUT the hostnames are being set correctly.  Example:

```
# docker exec -it web-services_elasticsearch.e3eaakkldj7pa3ygwkqwxts4i.7gjyxyjfjscve6rw41of7fyld hostname
fc2900a7227a
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One must set the hostname and node.name to "{{.Node.Hostname}}" and then list all the possible hostnames in the `cluster.initial_master_nodes` environment.  The "{{.Node.Hostname}}" will be the hostname of the docker swarm node.

The following works.

```
elasticsearch:
  image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.3
  hostname: "{{.Node.Hostname}}"
  environment:
    - node.name={{.Node.Hostname}}
    - cluster.name=ds-cluster
    - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms10g -Xmx10g"
    - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch
    - cluster.initial_master_nodes=fqdn1.domainname.com,fqdn2.domainname.com,fqdn3.domainname.com,fqdn4.domainname.com,fqdn5.domainname.com,fqdn6.domainname.com
    - node.ml=false
    - xpack.ml.enabled=true
    - xpack.monitoring.enabled=true
    - xpack.monitoring.collection.enabled=true
    - xpack.security.enabled=false
    - xpack.watcher.enabled=true
    - bootstrap.memory_lock=false
  networks:
    - backend
  volumes:
    - elasticsearch_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  deploy:
    mode: global
    endpoint_mode: dnsrr
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: 20G
```